# Как найти нужный образ в Docker?

Tags: docker

Нужен образ Debian8+php7+mysql+apache2.

Пробую

```
docker search debian8+php7+apache+mysql
```

но выдает результаты совсем неискомые.

Может есть какие-то секреты для поиска? Или, может, есть возможность собрать свой образ?

Comment: Такие образы вообще собирать не принято. Обычно в одном контейнере один процесс. Т. е. отдельный контейнер с MySQL, отдельный с Apache и PHP. Конечно, собрать свой образ всегда можно, но надо ли?

Comment: Нужно запустить сайт на php7 параллельно с php5.6. Как это реализовать с помощью docker?

Comment: какой смысл вы вложили в слово «параллельно»?

Comment: на одном сервере, на одной копии debian

Answer (score 1):

Никаких [секретов поиска нет](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/search/). Потому, что искать то особо нечего. **Используйте официальные образы**, их не так уж и много, и комбинируйте из них ваше приложение.

Разные версии php живут [здесь](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/), MySQL лучше запускать [из отдельного образа](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) поверьте, так будет намного удобней. Собрать образ с установленными PHP/Nginx/MySQl - "раз плюнуть", но тогда смысл использования docker? Это уже будет похоже на "простой VPS". Да еще и заставит поддерживать образ в актуальном состоянии.

Ответ на комментарий:

> Нужно запустить сайт на php7 параллельно с php5.6. Как это реализовать с помощью docker?

Конечно! Для этого Docker и нужен - легко создавать, переносить, модифицировать и сохранять окружение проекта. Запуская "на одном сервере" разные комбинации ПО.

Допустим, что исходные файлы (наш проект) в директории `./www`:

```
# при запуске (тестировании) используем --rm, дабы не захломлять диск ненужным
docker run --rm -it -p 8080:80 -v $(pwd)/www:/var/www/html php:7-apache

# в другом терминале
docker run --rm -it -p 8081:80 -v $(pwd)/www:/var/www/html php:5.6-apache
```

Получаем работающий проект `http://localhost:8080` на php7 и `http://localhost:8081` на php5.6. Это просто пример, очень простой пример. В реальности будет сложнее, но суть останется.

Если нужно использовать реальные домены при разработке, то [вот отличная штука](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy)

Можно создать отдельные Docker-файлы для разных конфигураций. Я обычно использую директорию `docker/*` в корне проекта и там под-директории с разными конфигурациями для проекта, к примеру `docker/php7-apache`

p.s. Этот ответ достаточно многословен, и в общем был написан как реплика на комментарий. Сам когда-то пытался собирать образы и искать готовые решения, пока не понял, что в этом часто нет смысла. Для большинства проектов официальные образы самое то! Только заменяй конфигурацию и всё.